# Trim all values of the input by default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, components, antd

I have a reusable Input built on top-of Antd Input.

Now I have a prop trim which is a boolean.

If trim is true, we trim the leading and trailing white spaces as below.

```
export default function MyInput({ trim, onChange, ...props }) {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (trim) {
      e.target.value = e.target.value.trim();
    }
    onChange?.(e);
  };

  return <Input onChange={handleChange} {...props} />;
}
```

This works completely fine.

Code available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/default-trim-antd-input-qoconq?file=/myInput.js)

But is it a good approach?

If not what's the better alternative for achieving this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good approach. it defeats the purpose of React working with the [Virtual DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html). Avoid manipulating the DOM directly when using React. A good solution will be using a `state` to store the input, and feed the state back into the input using `value` property.

Review the code below:

```
export default function MyInput({ trim, onChange, ...props }) {
    const [input, setInput] = React.useState("");
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        if (trim) {
            setInput(e.target.value.trim());
        } else {
            setInput(e.target.value);
        }
        onChange?.(e);
     };

     return <Input onChange={handleChange} value={input} {...props} />;
}
```

With this approach, you are letting React manage the input for you, and you can read the input at any time using the state. You may want to pass the input state to your `props.onChange`.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Updated the Codesandbox to show how we can use this component as a standalone Input, Controlled Input, Input Inside Form.Item. This works perfectly well and as expected in all the cases.